# How to detect encrypted files with System.Security.Cryptography

Tags: c#, encryption

Newly I got familiar with this namespace and I did some works with it. Now I want to detect the stored encrypted files. I have a property in my software that it lets the user to decide whether produced file should be encrypted or not. In this way, when user is opening his produced file I should know is it encrypted or not to decrypt and extract the real data.

Answer (score 2):

The nature of encrypted files is that they don't have any identifying marks, except those that you append yourself after encryption.  They are just a random-seeming array of bytes.  If there were any pattern to them that you could detect, it would be a poor encryption.

However, there are some approaches you can take:

- change the file extension of files you encrypt to something that you define: e.g. MyFile.enc
- put a marker elsewhere in the file name: Myfile.encrypted.txt
- prepend some bytes to the file contents itself, something long enough that it would be very unlikely  to appear randomly

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think it's better to make it one way ticket! I mean, let's just encrypt all files! Not some do and the other ones not.

Comment: Changing the file extension to one of your own would be the best way.  This is how we handle it.

Comment: agreed, it's the easiest to parse out, and Windows Explorer (and I assume other OS's file explorers) uses a different icon for them.

Comment: The first paragraph is absolutely wrong, see my comment on SteveCzetty's answer. Of course, hinting that the file is encrypted by providing additional data is a well known practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading the file normally, and if the data read is not what you expect, try decrypting it.

Or, you could add a [decrypt] tag before the file if it needs to be decrypted.

Comment: I would not go this way, as it is not "fail fast" and you might run into trouble if the first part parses etc. E.g. say that the first to bytes indicate the number of elements and encryption sets them at 0000, is that a valid file?

Comment: @owlstead, Yeah that might be another trouble with that. I think I'm gonna encrypt all my files then I would know that every file that comes in, is encrypted.

Comment: @MahanGM that might be a very sensible approach if it fits in your use scenario: it keeps complexity to a minimum. Keep in mind that this will solve your problem, but it does not answer the question you posted on stackoverflow :)

Comment: @owlstead, Yeah I know it. But I can't do anything right now for that. I think it would be better to scan the file template. I don't know how but maybe I can put a template for my file and then examine it at input position I mean where the user is opening that file. Thanks for paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "detect" that a file is encrypted.  That would somewhat defeat the purpose, would it not?  But you can try to decrypt a suspected encrypted file and validate that the results are what you expect.  (Look for a specific signature in the decrypted data.)

Comment: Yeah that's true. I was looking for a method that just let the individual of encrypting to know this file is encrypted or not. I mean my self.

Comment: The purpose of encryption is not to hide if encryption is used or not used; encryption is used to provide confidentiality of the plain text data. CBC encryption can be pretty easily detected: the file has the same length as the block size * N and looks like random data. The problem is that this is probably not enough to distinguish it from plain text all by itself.